# What is the easiest way to solve $\int_0^2\int_{-\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-(y-1)^2}}}^{\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-(y-1)^2}}}(2x^2+2y^2)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$

Tags: integration

I am wondering if there is an easy way to calculate this integral. The original problem is to calculate the volume of the solid bouded by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2y$, the plane $z=0$ and the paraboloid $z=2(x^2+y^2)$.

I used polar coordinates but the cylinder is deslocated.

The way I solved was to deslocate the cylinder to the origin of the space $(x,y,z)$ and therefore deslocate the paraboloid but I wonder if there an easier way that Im not seeing.

Comment: This is simple, the answer is $\pi$, simply using polar coordinates, it is changed to $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} (2r^2)\,(r \mathrm dr\mathrm d \theta) $, that is $=2\cdot \frac{r^4}{4}  \theta \longrightarrow \pi$

Comment: but the answer is $3\pi$